# Cant touch or zoom in/out after sleep device

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a Android App with google Maps API v2, MainActivity is extends android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity and it work for me, but when my device go to sleep and opened again the map is still showing but i cant not touch to move or zoom in/out.

Comment: can u post some code?

Answer (score 0):

I've removed `.Fullscreen` theme from Mainfest for `MainActivy` and resolve it